# The best way to include images in android application package

Tags: android

I'm developing an application for android, the application shows a list of activities of a carnival. I want that the application has the images of every activiy to avoid the user has to download it when runs the application, and improve user experience's with the application.

To do it I have added the images for every activity as resource, but I don't know if this is the best way to do It. There are some limitation with Resource that I don't like for example you can't create subfolders in drawable folder to organize the images, the only characters accept as a resource name are [a-zA-Z0-9_], and others....

Is there any good way to do it? or I have to use resources if I want to avoid the user has to download the images.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can download images when user load your application first time then save it to sdcard.

When your application runs again check weather images available in sdcard or not.

If not then download images else use images from sdcard.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it's mandatory by the client that the applications must run offline with all images from the first run.

Comment: so you dont have any other choice you must need to put images in drawable folder.

Answer (score 1):

The android system is designed to have all of your drawable items (aka images) in the resources folder. If you want the images to be packaged with your app (rather than downloaded after the fact) they need to be included in res/drawable

Answer (score 1):

Its always better to have the images downloaded but if your requirement is that the application should have all the pictures beforehand then you can use the "assets" folder where I suppose there is no restriction with respect to the names of the pics. I have tried the following code and it works:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.activity_image);
    try {
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open("@ahd ka.png"), null);
        img.setImageDrawable(d);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have purposely used a png file with special characters in name just to show that the program runs. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but finally I will cotinue using resources because with resources android choose automatically the best image for screen. But in future versions with more time to the next release I will consider to use your suggestion, to avoid resource limitations.